# Windows 10 universal app factory install

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-universal

Other than delivering the windows 10 app in the Windows Store, is there any other way to deliver it?

The objective is that, when I turn on the laptop/device (out of the box experience), I want the Windows 10 app already factory installed, so the user does not have to "download" the app from the Windows Store.

Is there some "backdoor" that I can preload the windows 10 app while burning the windows 10 image to the laptop/device?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating the image that is applied to the machines at the factory you can include it when creating the image.

There are various types of apps and many types of licensing though.
Typically people ask for this type of thing as part of an enterprise deployment scenario. If that's what you're after then a provisioning solution once removed "from the box" is probably more appropriate. There are MDM and linked ActiveDirectory solutions for provisioning apps and device configuration. I suggest you start by looking for such.

**Update**
If not an enterprise scenario, how would you already have the apps on the machine when you take it out of the box? I think what you're really after is a way to set up the machine when you take it out of the box. For that I'd recommend [chocolately](https://chocolatey.org/about) as an easy way of getting a machine set up how you want it.

In terms of the types of apps you are installing there are different considerations for services, win32 apps and windows store apps. What you are installing and how you create an image can have different consequences.
There are many scenarios regarding licensing but consider an app that is licensed on a per machine basis. If you created an image for machines as they come from the factory (typically enterprises do this when buying a lot and want an easy way to have them preconfigured) then you can't put the same single use license on all machines.

Comment: Thanks!  Would you guide me the types of apps and the concerns on licensing?  My case is not an enterprise deployment.  Right out from the factory.